# Let A be a 7x3 matrix... the rank of A is:

Tags: linear-algebra

To preface, this is a study problem not a homework problem.

Let $A$ be a $7 \times 3$ matrix such that its null space is spanned by $[1,2,0]^T$, $[2,1,0]^T$, and $[1,-1,0]^T$.

The rank of A is: $1, 2, 3, 4, 6$?

So I know the answer is $1$ because, I've looked at the solution. I got the answer $2$.

What I did is the following: I found a basis for the null space by forming a matrix from the $3$ column vectors that span the null-space of $A$. The basis had dimension 1, so then nullity of $A$ is $1$. I know the $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{nullity}(a)$ is the number of columns, so $3-1 = \operatorname{rank} = 2$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please note the edits made. These will tell you how to write in mathjax, something utterly essential if you want to ask further questions on this site. Also, the basis for the null space has dimension $\mathbf{2}$ not $1$.

Comment: Very informative. Thanks.

Comment: You are  welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(1,2,0)^T$ is not a multiple of $(2,1,0)^T$, the nullity is at least $2$.

Also, given that the third coordinate is $0$, we know that the null space has dimension $2$.

Hence, the rank is $3-2=1$.

Your mistake is claiming that the nullity is $1$.